# Uploading Pictures and Videos through an app with Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, upload, video-upload

So for some reason, the upload speeds have been fluctuating. Some times, the speeds of the uploads are fine. At other times it seems to take a very long time or it won't load at all. How would I solve this issue I have with the app I am working on?

For a bit more of an explanation, the app uploads both video and images to a online database. You would go through a series of steps where you would fill stuff out and answer questions. Then you'll get to the fragment where you can upload a number of pictures and/or videos. Recently I made a change to the amount of pictures/video a user can upload, but I don't think that is effecting anything with the actual upload process. Currently right now, The uploads are working for both images and videos across the 3 recent android versions.

This started pretty recently and it hasn't done that since I have been working on the app. Thanks.

Comment: literally any code please... error stacktrace, envoirment description, anything... your question needs way more details

Comment: That's the thing. There's nothing wrong with the code itself. It wasn't an issue prior.

Comment: so you are basically asking why your connection is sometimes slower than usual? well, ask admin or net provider, make some speed tests, pings, inspect case in details... does this occur only on some network or all? emulator or device? you very should put a lot more detail in question, currenty it's like: my car sometimes rides slower, why? literally hundreds of possible causes and fixes

Comment: Got you. I'll be more detailed in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like whoever was testing the upload speeds didn't have great internet connection. Once they were able to have access to good internet speeds, the uploads started working.